# Listing fields in a mongodb object

Tags: mongodb

I am developing a system where items can be shared with other users via an access key. I'm storing the access keys as fields within a `shareinfo` object (embedded within the item's document), as shown below:

```
shareinfo:{
    ........
    <nth key>: <permissions object - may be complex and large>
    ........
}
```

When an item is accessed I check shareinfo.key and find if its valid or not.

Currently, to list the keys I am loading (in Java) the entire shareinfo object in memory and running [keySet()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/BSONObject.html#keySet%28%29) on it to retrieve and return the keys *while the rest of the data is wasted*.

Here's the problem: I want to get the list of keys (i.e. object field names) without the accompanying data (because in some cases the permissions object is noticeably large).

I could not find any query in the mongodb docs for such a query. I want to know whether it's possible or not? Or is there an optimized way to load the list of field names into the application without the accompanying field values?

Comment: I'm afraid not. You can check for the existence of a field, but you cannot get a list of them.

Comment: I guess the best thing to do would be to keep the permission objects as small as possible.

btw do you have any idea if this thing is planned for the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB has a schema-less design, which means that any document could have different fields contained within it from any other document.  To get an exhaustive list of all the fields for all the documents, you would need to traverse all the documents in the collection and enumerate each field.  For any reasonably sized collection this is going to be an extremely expensive operation.

There are a couple of helpers that make this more simple: [Variety](https://github.com/variety/variety) and [schema.js](http://skratchdot.com/projects/mongodb-schema/)  .  They both allow you to limit the documents inspected, and they report on coverage as well.  Both amount to doing a map/reduce on the collections, but are at least simpler than having to write one yourself.

Comment: any idea how we could do the enumeration from java driver itself?
Also, if I specify the document then i guess the enumeration would be quite fast and efficient..

Comment: I'm not the greatest java dev, but I've put together a sample program to give you a demonstration of the technique.  It's found at [pastie](http://pastie.org/4758169).  It basically finds the first record in "yourcollection" and prints a list of key fields to System.out.

Comment: Thanks! It worked great... Our company has infact started to study MongoDB source to implement this and few other features at the backend...

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when trying to understand the structure of an existing mongodb database using the mongodb shell. Then I found that I can use the JavaScript function Object.keys() to retrieve an array of the object fields. (Tested with MongoDb 2.4.2)

```
Object.keys(db.collection.findOne())
```

Comment: This is really helpful, and I'm surprised this isn't very well documented - thanks!

Comment: It's just basics of JavaScript, just look at JavaScript documentation, not mongodb. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys By the way, this query will show keys of 1st document, not all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for top-level fields across all documents (don't care about sub-fields and all the details statistics provided by variety)

Here is the one-liner

```
db.things.aggregate([{$project: {arrayofkeyvalue: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"}}}, {$unwind:"$arrayofkeyvalue"}, {$group:{_id:null, allkeys:{$addToSet:"$arrayofkeyvalue.k"}}}])
```